# How to convert variable/fields value into IBM signed numeric values in Partially Free Format RPG

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am trying to convert variable values from zoned decimal format to character but in doing so, I need the code to convert them as per IBM standards, In old RPG codes most developers have used opcode MOVEL and MLLZO but what are the substitute command for partially free format RPG.

```
 *For example, the result of below code will be var2 = 1234N 
D var1     s       10s 2    inz(-123.45)
D var2     s       10      
 /Free
C           MOVEL   var1 var2
            dsply var2;
            *Inlr = *on;
 /End-free
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When MOVEL moves a numeric value to a character field, the character field basically gets the zoned-decimal value of the numeric value.

%EDITC with the X edit code does this.

var2 = %editc (var1 : 'X');

But for each case where you want to convert a numeric value like -123.45 to a character like '1234N', it's a good idea to consider exactly why your code needs that kind of value. Perhaps you need to look at how the result of the MOVEL is being used. Instead of just converting the MOVEL to free-form, you might want to combine several statements into a procedure that accomplishes the entire business goal of the code containing the MOVEL statement.

Comment: May I ask you why you decided to not translate the all of the old opcodes to free form bifs? Wouldn't it be easier for "older" developers who are comfortable with opcodes because they have used them all over there career, to migrate there code to free form?

Comment: The commonly discussed reason for the deprecation of `MOVE` is because a developer can NOT tell what it's doing by looking at it.  You have to examine the source and target variables and then remember a bunch of esoteric rules.  Much easier to understand the explicit RPG IV built in functions.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.